# Put together two selects into one

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Could you help me put the second select into first one? I need calculate rate of type in first select. Second select works good.

First select:

```
WITH "global" AS (
 SELECT
  m.id
  ,json_build_array(
      ce.payload->>'Name',
      ce.payload->>'Date',
      ce.payload->>’Type,
      ce.payload->>’Rate’,
      row_number() over (partition by m.id order by ce.payload->>’Date’ desc)) as "value"
FROM public."events" ce
LEFT OUTER JOIN "external"."mapping" m
    ON ce.id=m.id
WHERE ce.type IN ('cs_calls','pc_calls')
    AND coalesce(ce.payload ->> 'Name', '')!=''
    AND m.id IS NOT NULL
 )

SELECT
    id,
    value
FROM “global”
```

Second select:

```
select 
id,
cast(issue as float)/cast(total_count as float) as Rate
from (select 
    id,
    sum(case when type='Issue' then 1 else 0 end) as issue,
   count(*) total_count 
    from events
    GROUP BY id)
```

Comment: in second select where the `id` is coming from? and that `id` is similar to the first one?

Comment: sorry, I repaired it. yes, id is same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Id` is the way to join this tables then you can try the following

```
select 
    g.id,
    g.value,
    ((issue * 1.0) / total_count) as Rate
from 
(
    select 
        id,
        sum(case when type='Issue' then 1 else 0 end) as issue,
        count(*) total_count 
    from events
    group by
    id
 ) e
join global g
on e.id = g.id
```

Comment: Error executing [events]: SQLSTATE[42702]: Ambiguous column: 7 ERROR:  column reference "id" is ambiguous LINE 28:     id,

Comment: you may be missing something, after `CTE`, place the above query. it should run.

Comment: Thank you Zealous, Is it possible add Rate to value? (to json_build_array what I created in first select)